# Launch a new activity and clear the instance when it is alreday in activity stack?

Tags: android

I have a home activity say H, a data detail activity say D, a list activity say L

Now the steps and stack:

1. Launch app: H
2. Go to Detail from H: H > D
3. Go to list: H > D > L (the flag of the intent to launch D is FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
4. Go to Detail: H > L > D

That works fine, D will call onNewIntent instead of onCreate.
But I wonder is there any way to start a new activity D so it will call onCreate instead of onNewIntent?

Comment: why does it matter if onCreate gets executed instead of onNewIntent?  Couldn't you just wrap whatever you need to do inside another method and call that from both?

Comment: I got 5 fragments in the detail screen, each of them has different data set. If the onNewIntent get executed then I have to clear all the previous data sets and set new data sets for each fragment.

Comment: Not knowing anything else about your activities and fragments, something tells me there's an elegant solution where you simply separate your data from your UI.